# Reading marriage bond from 1838 Kentucky USA?

Tags: united-states, marriage-records, palaeography

I was hoping to find the name of the father of Mary Ann Sims from this marriage bond.

[image]

but I cannot read the name:

[image]

Does this just say "Mr. A Sims ? Date"?   If so, would William A Sims be another relative (not the father)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is "Mr A. Sims, Dec[eased], late of Nicholas County". (It could be "Wm A. Sims" instead, though, with Wm being short for William, but that first letter is a better match to the other instances of "M" on the page, and a poor one to "W".)

If the "Deceased" part is right, he's probably not the one putting up the fifty pounds bond. In which case, William A. Sims must be another relative of Maryann - a brother or uncle, perhaps.

Comment: Could be that the did not know if he was deceased (hence the question mark).